# Minimum Path in number line

Tags: data-structures

On a number line from negative infinite to positive infinite, if you start from 0, you can either jump back or front. but every jump length is 1 more than the previous jump. Given a number on the number line, can we reach it using any combination of jumps. If yes, print the minimum length path

Comment: Are the jump sizes all integers? Do they start at size one? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: For the first question, yes it is always reachable as you can use +n, -(n+1) to subtract 1, and -n + (n+1) to add 1. You can repeat this forever. Shortest path requires a little more thought.

Comment: Yes jump sizes are all integers

Comment: Probably, you should do a little work with a pencil and paper to discover this for yourself. Start by figuring out how you would get the value 2. Assuming that your first jump is 1 (forward or backward), next jump is 2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an interview question, so I will not give an elaborate solution. However, try to prove the following (<sup>n</sup>Σ(i) stands for summation from 1 to *n*):

> For all integers in `{ k : k <`<sup>n</sup>Σ(i)`,`<sup>n</sup>Σ(i)`- k is odd, k ϵ N }`, *k* cannot be reached from 0 using any combination of back or forth jumps of length 1 up to length *n*.

Using this, the answer to your question becomes fairly simple. If you still have any difficulties, please mention in the comments.